# Git removes files in vendor

Tags: git

I need the files in my vendor directory tracked in git.  I know that's not usual, but I have to deliver everything to an isolated network as a single package.  It's a requirement of the client.  Anyway, I've vendored 16 dependencies.  Fourteen are working exactly like I would expect.  Two dependencies will just not stay.  This is NOT a result of the .gitignore.  I have removed the .git directory from the dependency.  I'm using git version 2.1.2.  But still, git will just not add the files to the repo.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked through the issues.  First I ran the following code:

```
for X in `find /projects/go/src/c2s/vendor -type f`
do
    git add --force $X
done
```

That worked for one of the 2 problem children.  The second produced the following errors:

```
fatal: Pathspec '/projects/go/src/c2s/vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama/.travis.yml' is in submodule 'vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama'
fatal: Pathspec '/projects/go/src/c2s/vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama/CHANGELOG.md' is in submodule 'vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama'
...
...
fatal: Pathspec '/projects/go/src/c2s/vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama/LICENSE' is in submodule 'vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama'
fatal: Pathspec '/projects/go/src/c2s/vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama/Makefile' is in submodule 'vendor/github.com/Shopify/sarama'
```

I found [Removing Submodules](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-remove-a-submodule-in-git/13228) which gives the following directions:

````
Delete the section referring to the submodule from the .gitmodules file
Stage the changes via git add .gitmodules
Delete the relevant section of the submodule from .git/config.
Run git rm --cached path_to_submodule (no trailing slash)
Run rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule
Commit the changes with ```git commit -m "Removed submodule "
Delete the now untracked submodule files rm -rf path_to_submodule
````

Then I ran my script above again and everything stuck!